# shell operation within makefile

Tags: shell, make

I have the following line in my makefile:

```
var  := $(sort $(foreach m,$(libs),$($(m)-objs)))
```

which I changed: it now uses sort from the shell:

```
var  := $(shell echo $(foreach m,$(libs),$($(m)-objs)) | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ' ' )
```

But it turns out that after my modification *$(var)* is empty. What did I do wrong?

EDIT:
I was trying to substitute gnu-make builtin sort with bash sort, because I wanted to have more flexibility over process of sorting. It turned out that output from foreach is strange. I reproduced the problem with the following makefile:

```
a-obj := hhh lll
b-obj := zzz aaa
x := a b
xx := $(shell echo $(foreach m,$(x),$($(m)-obj)) | tr ' ' '\n' | sort)
yy := $(sort $(foreach m,$(x),$($(m)-obj)))

all:
    @echo $(xx)
    @echo $(yy)
```

which gives the expected output:

```
$ make
aaa hhh lll zzz
aaa hhh lll zzz
```

I am sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I don't know anything about the makefile format but don't you need to somehow group the commands you want to echo? Something like `echo $( $(foreach m,$(libs),$($(m)-objs)) | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | tr '\n' ' ')`?

Comment: @terdon it does not help

Comment: Can you try with the `execute:` target for printing the result? Using `$(shell)`  makes recipes are implicitly using the shell. The problem with this is that it moves the work into the command expansion phase, which means it can’t run in parallel. The solution for this one is not use $(shell).

Comment: I find out the solution: second tr command eats trailing new line character which I append with: `... | sed 's/.*/&\n/'`

Comment: Works for me. Post a [complete code example that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Tell us what version of make you're using.